# Как в связи many-to-many пропустить повторяющуюся запись? EF C#

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, asp.net, entity-framework

Есть таблицы Subjects(SubjectId,Name, keys) и KeyWords(Id,Word(индекс)) отношение многие ко многим. У KeyWords есть поле Word, которое имеет атрибут unique. Пользуюсь EF c MS SQL. Не знаю как проверить есть ли при добавлении в таблице KeyWords в поле Word уже такие ключевые слова. Возможно ли это сделать без дополнительных запросов на проверку существования каждого Word в KeyWords?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил через объявление переменной временной таблицы, вставки в нее ключевых слов.

```
  Declare @temp_keywords table (
        AKeyword <type(length>);
        Insert into @temp_keywords (AKeyword) values ('keyword1');
        Insert into @temp_keywords (AKeyword) values ('keyword2');
        ..
        Insert into @temp_keywords (AKeyword) values ('keywordN');

        Select AKeyword as word
        Into Keywords
        FROM @temp_keywords
        Where @temp_keywords.AKeyword not in (
                   select word
                   from keywords
                   where Id=ASubjectId)
```